# How to get less captchas?

Tags: security, browser

On my Linux computer, I get captchas constantly, even some Web sites where I do shopping regularly, I'll get stopped every day on (e.g. Walmart.com, Amazon.com, etc.).

On my Windows 10 computer, using the same browser, Firefox, I don't see the captchas, even on the same sites.

I assume the Web sites think because I'm using Linux, "I'm therefore a robot". Is there any way to fix that problem?

Comment: Are your browser's security/privacy settings (and privacy add-ons, if you're using any) set exactly the same in both OSs?

Comment: I use no browser addons, but I recall following a detailed "lockdown" guide for security the one on Linux. Can't find the link anywhere now, but is like this: https://privacysavvy.com/security/safe-browsing/firefox-privacy-security-ultimate-guide/#:~:text=%20Some%20vital%20heads-ups%20before%20securing%20your%20Firefox,safe%20online%20is%20to%20have%20a...%20More%20

Comment: Well, if the specific instructions you followed included changing the browser's *user agent string* to a non-standard value, that would explain the abundance of captchas: you are stating you are not a standard browser, therefore you might be a bot.

Answer (score 1):

Sign-in with a Google account, because captcha is a Google product or use a browser add-on e,g: [Buster: Captcha Solver for Humans](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/buster-captcha-solver/)